# Align text and button on the same row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align this text and button but I can't manage to do it. I want them to be on the same row no matter the length of the text.

If you need the CSS styling please let me know.

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;" class="sapMktBlock">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width: 100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 0px;" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="640" align="center" style="width: 640px; min-width: 640px;" class="wrapto100pc">
          <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width: 100%;" class="wrapto100pc">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="">
                  <table bgcolor="#f5f5f5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="min-width: 100%;" width="100%" role="presentation">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 0; direction: ltr;">
                                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" dir="ltr"><tr><td valign="middle"><![endif]-->
                                  <div style="direction: ltr; max-width: 320px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;" class="wrapto100pc">
                                    <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wrapto100pc" dir="ltr">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mobheightclear">
                                            <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;" class="BDpad">
                                                    <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: 'Arial Black', Arial, Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size: 32px; line-height: 30px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter">
                                                          <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;"> DONE <br> </a>
                                                            <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                                            <br> </a>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter"> Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;" class="textcenter">
                                                            <table style="display: inline-block;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta">
                                                              <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                  <td>
                                                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ctainner" style="width: 210px; min-width: 210px;">
                                                                      <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                          <td bgcolor="#f8f3e8" align="center" style=" padding: 9px 12px 9px 12px; border: 1px solid #f8f3e8; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ">
                                                                          <a target="_blank" href="" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; display: block;" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Shop them all </a> </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                      </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                  </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                              </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:0;"><![endif]-->
                                  <div style="direction: ltr; max-width: 320px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;" class="wrapto100pc">
                                    <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wrapto100pc" dir="ltr">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mobheightclear">
                                            <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;" class="BDpad">
                                                    <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: 'Arial Black', Arial, Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size: 32px; line-height: 30px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter">
                                                          <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;"> STOPE <br> </a>
                                                            <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                                            <br> </a>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;" class="textcenter">
                                                            <table style="display: inline-block;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta">
                                                              <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                  <td>
                                                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ctainner" style="width: 210px; min-width: 210px;">
                                                                      <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                          <td bgcolor="#f8f3e8" align="center" style=" padding: 9px 12px 9px 12px; border: 1px solid #f8f3e8; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ">
                                                                          <a target="_blank" href="" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; display: block;" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Shop them all </a> </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                      </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                  </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                              </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size: 0px;" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really nasty way of coding! no offense! you should separate HTML and CSS for clear understanding.

Comment: it isn't nasty. This is required in emails to have the css in lined

Comment: Sorry if that hurt you!, even though if you want to be in the same file at-least you can have your code within `<script></script>` tag so that you don't have to worry about fixing issue when you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your requirement we would need to make some changes in the structure of your table. we need to keep button and text in the same  and with different s.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width: 100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 0px;" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="640" align="center" style="width: 640px; min-width: 640px;" class="wrapto100pc">
      <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width: 100%;" class="wrapto100pc">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="">
              <table bgcolor="#f5f5f5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="min-width: 100%;" width="100%" role="presentation">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 0; direction: ltr;">
                              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" dir="ltr"><tr><td valign="middle"><![endif]-->
                              <div style="direction: ltr; max-width: 320px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;" class="wrapto100pc">
                                <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wrapto100pc" dir="ltr">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr width="320" style="max-width:320px">
                                      <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mobheightclear">
                                        <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="320" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;" class="BDpad">
                                                <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr width="320">
                                                      <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: 'Arial Black', Arial, Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size: 32px; line-height: 30px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter">
                                                      <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;"> DONE <br> </a>
                                                        <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                                        <br> </a>
                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td width="160" align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter"> Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum   Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum   Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum  </td>
<td width="160" align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;" class="textcenter">
                                                        <table style="display: inline-block;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta">
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td>
                                                                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ctainner" style="width: 210px; min-width: 210px;">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                      <td bgcolor="#f8f3e8" align="center" style=" padding: 9px 12px 9px 12px; border: 1px solid #f8f3e8; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ">
                                                                      <a target="_blank" href="" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; display: block;" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Shop them all </a> </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>

                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size:0;"><![endif]-->
                              <div style="direction: ltr; max-width: 320px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;" class="wrapto100pc">
                                <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wrapto100pc" dir="ltr">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mobheightclear">
                                        <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 20px;" class="BDpad">
                                                <table width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: 'Arial Black', Arial, Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight: 900; font-size: 32px; line-height: 30px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter">
                                                      <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;"> STOPE <br> </a>
                                                        <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                                        <br> </a>
                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="left" style=" padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #000000; " class="textcenter"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;" class="textcenter">
                                                        <table style="display: inline-block;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="cta">
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td>
                                                                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ctainner" style="width: 210px; min-width: 210px;">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                      <td bgcolor="#f8f3e8" align="center" style=" padding: 9px 12px 9px 12px; border: 1px solid #f8f3e8; color: #000000; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; ">
                                                                      <a target="_blank" href="" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; display: block;" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Shop them all </a> </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="font-size: 0px;" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Try above snippet. It might work for you. I have made few changes in structure of table.

Comment: that's not working. Check and you will see. You can put a code snippet here so is easier to see that your code is not right, thanks anyway

Comment: check once again. I have updated the code. It is just for left section. Please try once and let me know